# Jquery Validate Switch Validator Form

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

So I have one form, Form A. Originally the validator is attached to Form A, however at some point I clone Form A and this produces Form B. Now, I want the same rules from Form A to apply to Form B, however currently the validator is being cloned along with the form, and that validator is still pointing to Form A. So, to summarize, my new, cloned validator is pointing to Form A rather then Form B. What is the ideal way to resolve this problem (the less hacky the better :))

Comment: you should at least show us some code, this makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realize that my question was a bit non-specific, however I've solved my problem for any also hitting the problem. What I did to solve it was first remove the validator on the clone like so:

`clone.find('form').removeData("validator");`

then just rebinding the validator:

```
clone.find('form').validate({        
    //more stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After cloning, you will have two identical blocks of code.

Since it is not permitted to have elements with identical IDs on the page, you can change or rename the ID attributes. Show us the code and we'll show you how.

If there are javascript/jQuery events bound to those elements, any renamed elements will leave the DOM and become like injected elements (*in fact, the cloned elements are considered injected elements already since they did not exist in the DOM originally*). So, you will need to use the jQuery `.on()` method for those elements. For example, suppose you clone an `<input>` field that has a click event attached to it:

```
<input id="book_1" type="text" />
```

After cloning, you will have two identical input fields:

```
<input id="book_1" type="text" />
<input id="book_1" type="text" />
```

You can rename the second input field (we can help with this, perhaps in a new question), so that it is:

```
<input id="book_1" type="text" />
<input id="book_2" type="text" />
```

But then any code must be updated, like this:

```
$('#book_1').click(function() {
    alert('Clicked me!');
});
$(document).on('click', '#book_2', function() {
    alert('Clicked me!');
});
```

Note that you could use the latter structure with the original element also, but you cannot use the first structure with an injected (or modified) element.

Also, since you must not have identically-named IDs on the page, any IDs that you do not wish to update should be changed to classes.

If you have further questions, I suggest that you create a second, more specific question and post your code so that we can help you to accomplish programatically what you need.